# Disable (or filter) Hot Corners

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have a background app that, when a specific app is open, I want to disable any Hot Corners. Is there anyway to 'intercept' or 'filter' these events? Or perhaps another way to accomplish this that I am not thinking of?

Note: The app is written in Objective-C.

Comment: Basically what do you mean by hot corners ??

Comment: System Preferences -> Mission Control -> Hot Corners... (Bottom Left).

You can setup a few actions to perform when your mouse touches the edges of the screen.

Comment: Oh so you want to disable system preference mission control through programatically right??

Comment: I'm not certain if hot corners is tied to mission control other than in the settings. If I were to disable mission control, are you certain that it would disable the hot corners?

Comment: Sorry i am not getting exactly what you wanted to achieve if you want to disable the same through code then using applescript it is possible.

Comment: I want to disable it in Objective-C in code.

Comment: are you sandboxed (for App Store) or free to do anything?

Comment: @ehftwelve you can call the apple script and then call inside cocoa method it will be easy

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is "not really".

An app has some options for itself, but that doesn't fit with your desire to do it in a background app to affect a different app. Those options include capturing the display(s) and, maybe, setting the presentation options (`-[NSApplication setPresentationOptions:]`).

You might try setting up a [Quartz event tap](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html) and simply swallowing any mouse-move event that is in (or would move beyond) the screen corner(s). I don't know if you want to disable all hot corners or only those corners assigned to a specific function. You can query the hot corners using AppleScripts like the following. Translating that into the Scripting Bridge is left as an exercise for the reader:

```
tell application "System Events"
    get activity of top left screen corner of expose preferences
end tell
```