# Temporarily disable hot-corners and dock screen switching

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a full screen borderless `NSWindow` that requires the user to move their mouse to the edges and the corners of the screen often. Unfortunately these movements can trigger the hot-corner actions as well as switching the dock to another screen.

Is there any way to temporarily disable this behaviour while the window is being shown?

Comment: Have you tried running the window modally?

Comment: @stevesliva Just tried it and it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the answer is 'not really' except if you capture all mouse events for the entire screen.

For a complete answer and possible solution, I leave you to Ken answer here : [Disable (or filter) Hot Corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611143/disable-or-filter-hot-corners)